# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'type'

Tags: python

I am having trouble and getting error with this code...
Can someone help me to sort out this problem.?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVTvj.png)

[ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'blues'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVTvj.png)

Comment: 'str' is a type, therefore a reserved keyword. You can't cast a type to another type. Post more details for a more thorough answer.

Comment: looks like you have a variable named `str`. change it. `str` is a keyword.

Comment: What is float(str) in your code?

Comment: You can certainly use `str` as a variable name. `str` is not a reserved keyword, but a built-in type. @RalviIsufaj

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what others are saying, you can certainly use `str` as a variable name. `str` is not a reserved keyword, but a built-in type.

That being said, the code `float(str)` returns an error because you haven't overridden the variable `str`. You are passing the wrong argument to `float()`

Comment: Thank you GrandPhuba.. I had taken wrong image of my error..Can you re-check my error and give me its solution..

Comment: @SangpoLama it would really help the people trying to help you if you follow the site guidelines when asking a question. For starters, shows your code in your question (not as a link to an image), as well as the errors. You can learn more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask